# MYSQL Deleting all tables in database older than X Days

Tags: mysql

I have mysql server along with syslog-ng on Ubuntu. the syslog server creates tables in database on daily basis based on dates example

- 2020_12_29
- 2020_12_28
- 2020_12_27
- 2020_12_26

I know how to delete records in table, like

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE date(acctstarttime) < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH);"
```

BUT I want to delete tables older than x days to avoid disk filling up 100%. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

Schematically (debugging needed):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE drop_old_tables (the_date DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE tablename VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
      AND STR_TO_DATE(TABLE_NAME, '%Y_%m_%d') < the_date;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur;
REPEAT:
    FETCH cur INTO tablename;
    SET @sql := CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', tablename);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE cur;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transition away from a date based table, you could use the [create-statement-append](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.22/administration-guide/49#TOPIC-1209254) to add a partitioning scheme to an existing table. This is compatible with the way [the table definition is formed](https://github.com/syslog-ng/syslog-ng/blob/67784a5f86e1298bfb8c7bc4d643f5d1ba732532/modules/afsql/afsql.c#L560).

```
create-statement-append(PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(dt)) (
    PARTITION future       VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
))
```

Then use a [MySQL event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) to [drop partitions and create new partitions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-partition-operations.html)

If you are lucky enough to be using MariaDB(10.2+), [execute immediate](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) and the [drop partition if exists](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/) makes the scripting of this easier:

Delete the old partitions in the new day:

```
CREATE EVENT purgeolddays
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO execute immediate concat('
   alter table tbl drop partition if exists 
     from', date_format(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY),'%Y%m%d')
)
```

And to add new partitions before the day arrives:

```
CREATE EVENT addnextday
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO execute immediate concat(
  'alter table tbl  REORGANIZE PARTITION future 
     INTO ( PARTITION from', date_format(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y%m%d'),  '
       VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS("', date(now()), '")),
     PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE)'
)
```

Note the [event_scheduler](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#event_scheduler) needs to be enabled (and it isn't by default).

Ref: [dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=2e1e32dd0f92d8d46eb435ef94413aa1)

And thanks to [Rick James' partition guide](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)